# Generics in Swift - "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Tags: ios, generics, swift3

I'd like to return a `UIViewController` conforming to `MyProtocol` from a method, so I'm using the method signature:

```
func myMethod<T where T : UIViewController, T : MyProtocol>() -> T {
```

First thing I don't understand: if `myMethod` returns e.g. a `MyViewController` which has to following signature, I have to force cast it:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol
```

I cannot simply `return MyViewController()` but I need to cast it like this: `return MyViewController() as! T` - why is this necessary?

And the second thing: how can I use this method somewhere? I cannot simply say

```
let x = myMethod() as? UIViewController
```

as I get the error

```
Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
```

How can I achieve something like this? If I cast it to `MyViewController` it works, but I would like to avoid that of course.

**EDIT: Example**

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController, MyProtocol {
}

protocol MyProtocol {
}

func myMethod<T>() -> T where T : UIViewController, T : MyProtocol {
    return MyViewController() as! T // why is the cast necessary?
}
```

ok, I do get one part, but why is the cast to `T` necessary? `MyViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` and conforms to the protocol, so no cast should be necessary, right?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Why are you using generics in the first place?

Comment: I would like to work with a type that's a `UIViewController` and conforms to the specific protocol; I do have different classes which conform to this rules, therefore I do not want to use a specific type.

Comment: don't you want to accept an answer?

Answer (score 46):

```
func myMethod<T where T : UIViewController, T : MyProtocol>() -> T
```

This declaration says: There exists a function called `myMethod`, such that `myMethod` returns some *specific* `T` where `T` is a subtype of `UIViewController` and also `MyProtocol`. This does not say what type `T` actually is, and it does not say that there is only one such `myMethod`. There can be many if there are many type that are both subclasses of `UIViewController` and conform to `MyProtocol`. Every one of those types creates a new version of `myMethod` (really a new solution to the assertion `myMethod` makes, that such a function does exist).

This is not the same thing as:

```
func myMethod() -> UIViewController
```

That says: The function `myMethod` returns any subtype of `UIViewController`.

There is no way in Swift to express "any type that is a subclass of UIViewController and is a subtype of MyProtocol." You can only discuss a specific type that meets that criterial. Swift can't combine classes and protocols this way; it's just a current limitation of the language, not a deep design issue.

The *specific* versus *any* is the issue. There are many functions that satisfy your `myMethod` declaration. Every `T` you can plug in that conforms to the rules would be a candidate. So when you say `myMethod()`, the compiler doesn't know which specific `T` you mean.

(I was going to expand this answer to provide it in less type-theory, more "how do you do it in code" terms, but donnywals already has an excellent version of that.)

*** To your edited question ***

```
func myMethod<T>() -> T where T : UIViewController, T : MyProtocol {
    return MyViewController() as! T // why is the cast necessary?
}
```

`T` is a *specific* type decided by the caller. It is not "any type that conforms" it is "some specific, concrete type that conforms." Consider the case that you called:

```
let vc: SomeOtherViewController = myMethod()
```

In this case, `T` is `SomeOtherViewController`. `MyViewController` is not that type, so what you're doing with the `as!` cast is dangerous.

Answer (score 19):

In a method like this, returning `T` means you have to return `T`. If you return `MyViewController`, the return type should be `MyViewController`. `T` is a generic type that will take the form of whatever the Swift compiler can infer it to be.

So, with your method signature, a simple implementation of the protocol and method could look like this.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var name: String { get set }
}

func myMethod<T where T : UIViewController, T : MyProtocol>() -> T {
    var vc = T()
    vc.name = "Hello, world"
    return vc
}
```

So, considering your usage example:

```
let x = myMethod()
```

How would the compiler know what the concrete type of `T` is? There is nothing giving it a hint of `MyViewController`. The only thing we know is that whatever `T` is, it should be `MyViewController` or a subclass of it. And it should conform to `MyProtocol`. But this does not provide information about what the type of `T` should be.

The only place where the compiler can infer what we want `T` to be is through the return value. All the code between `<>` are constraints for what `T` is allowed to be. `-> T` is the only place where `T` is seen outside of the constraints. So if we can somehow tell the compiler what we want `myMethod` to return, we have given it enough information to infer `T`.

Your typecast works but I agree that it's not very pretty. A much prettier way for the compiler to infer `T` is this.

```
let vc: MyViewController = myMethod()
```

By specifying the type of `vc`, the compiler understands that we want `myMethod` to return a `MyViewController`. So now `T`'s type can be inferred and if we return `T`, we actually return `MyViewController`.

Comment: @donnywals how about on generic method parameters, not the return type? How do you infer something like that?

Comment: I guess this means you are limited in how you nest calls when returning generics. Like function A -> B -> C where B & C both return generics. In my specific case I'm calling an API and want to pass back a Decodable. The C call returned this, but I needed to layer in security so I created a B call as a wrapper which got the bearertoken and passed it off to C. Only way to do this was to return C directly from B.

Answer (score 4):

As some pointed out in the comments, there is no apparent reason for `myMethod` to be generic. The argument for doing so is: (quoting from your comment)

> I would like to work with a type that's a UIViewController and conforms to the specific protocol;

Lets call that type `ViewControllerAndMyprotocol`,

> I do have different classes which conform to this rules, therefore I do not want to use a specific type

However `myMethod` signature already constrains the type `ViewControllerAndMyprotocol` i.e. caller is bound to receive a `UIViewController` and not any of the "different classes which conform to this rules".

The flexibility on what concrete types could be `ViewControllerAndMyprotocol`, including `MyViewController` is why there is type ambiguity in the statement `let x = myMethod()` requiring casting: `let x = myMethod() as? UIViewController`

You can avoid the casting by changing `myMethod` signature as such:

```
typealias ViewControllerAndMyprotocol = UIViewController & MyProtocol

func myMethod() -> ViewControllerAndMyprotocol {
   return MyViewController()
}
```

The statement `let x = myMethod()` will not require casting and will be of type `ViewControllerAndMyprotocol` which is also a `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 3):

Very Easy Way **Your Function**:
you just need to add ? mark with the model object

```
func decodeDataToObject<T: Codable>(data : Data?)->T?{

}
```

**Calling Method**

```
let model: ModelDataClass? = self.decodeDataToObject(data: response.data!)
```

**Example for understanding**: you can see i have use ? with the model name after declaring the object

```
let model: ModelDataClass?
```