# Operating on Generic Collections in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, collections, swift4

I am writing some code that, ideally, would be able to operate on anything that can be subscripted with a `String`. Here's an example:

```
class MyClass {
    func getValue<DataSource>(key: String, from dataSource: DataSource) -> Any? where DataSource: Collection, DataSource.Index == String {
        return dataSource[key]
    }
}

let data: [String: Any] = [
    "why": "is this not working"
]

MyClass().getValue(key: "why", from: data) // Compile error!
```

The error I receive is `Generic parameter "DataSource" could not be inferred`. I cannot figure out why this is not valid code. I have a feeling there's some nuance of covariance/contravariance that I have not digested properly. In any case, is it even possible to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999102/generics-in-swift-generic-parameter-t-could-not-be-inferred this is a good read about generic inference

Comment: In this case `DataSource.Index` is `Dictionary<String, Any>.Index` and not `String`. Other remark: better return `DataSource.Element?` instead of `Any?`

Comment: @Carpsen90 You are correct about the index. According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/index),  the index isn't the type of the key at all, although you are able to subscript with just the key.