# Swift : Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have a protocol called `P`, and I want to write a function that would return an instance of any type conforming to that protocol.

I wrote this:

```
func f<T: P>() -> T? {
    // ... 
}
```

But then when I try to call it:

```
var fp = f()
```

I get this error: `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`. What am I doing wrong and how to solve this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What type `fp` supposed to be? Even I, human, cannot infer it.

Comment: Maybe could be helpful: [Generics in Swift - "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999102/generics-in-swift-generic-parameter-t-could-not-be-inferred)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're very close. Say you have a `struct` `A` that conforms to `P`. Then you could specify the generic parameter as follows:

```
var fp: A? = f()
```

Without that information, the compiler can't know what type `fp` should be.

Comment: Hi and thank you! Well, I'm beginning to understand, but still I have another question: what if I have, say, two structs `S1` and `S2`, each conforming to `P`, and want to create a function that could return either an instance of `S1` or of  `S2`? With classes I would have created a `C` class conforming to `S`, and then the two sub-types would inherit `C`, but here I'm stuck with structs.

Comment: You can return either `S1` or `S2` from that function as long as they conform to `P`, that's no problem at all. You don't need to specify that the return type is a union of `S1` and `S2` (actually you can't directly do that in Swift right now). Do you _only_ want to return either of those two?

Comment: Well actually it's just an example, I could for sure want to return any struct conforming to `P` and there could be 10 different ones...

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but why aren't your problem solved with the code you've shown and my solution? I can return any type I want that conforms to `P`.

Comment: It is actually. Thank you for your answers!